# What's the best way to call mutiple api continuous? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have a question about call API method.
If I have three API.
First, I call A API, and get it's response `dataA`.
Second, I call B API, and it's request need to take `dataA` to it's body, then get it's response `dataB`.
Third, I call C API, and it's request need to take `dataB` to it's body, then get it's response `dataC`.
If I have D,E,F API, the code doesn't look like pretty and easy.
Have any good idea to me?
Thanks.

```
    func callAFunction(completionHandler: @escaping (_ isSuccess: Bool, _ result: [String : String], _ errorMsg : String ) -> Void) {
        //API A
    }
    
    func callBFunction(aResponseSting: String ,completionHandler: @escaping (_ isSuccess: Bool, _ result: [String : String], _ errorMsg : String ) -> Void) {
        //API B
    }
    
    func callCFunction(bResponseSting: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ isSuccess: Bool, _ result: [String : String], _ errorMsg : String ) -> Void) {
        //API C
    }
    
    func testAPI() {
        
        self.callAFunction { (isSuccess, dataA, errorMsg) in
            
            if isSuccess {
                
                self.callBFunction(aResponseSting: dataA["data"] ?? "") { (isSuccess, dataB, errorMsg) in
                    
                    if isSuccess {
                        
                        self.callCFunction(bResponseSting: dataB["data"] ?? "") { (isSuccess, dataC, errorMsg) in
                            
                            //To call more API
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: What makes one way better than others?

Comment: See `DispatchGroup`.

Answer (score 2):

Given latest xcode release 13 `async - await`

```
func callAFunction() async -> [String : String] { }
func callBFunction(aResponseSting: String) async -> [String : String] { }    
func callCFunction(bResponseSting: String) async -> [String : String] { }
```

Then

```
let resA = await callAFunction()
let resB = await callBFunction(aResponseSting:resA["data"] ?? "")
let resC = await callCFunction(bResponseSting:resB["data"] ?? "")
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is to use Rxswift's flatMapLatest operator to process。

example:

```
/// Rx...
enum Api {

    /// get token
    static func token(username: String, password: String) -> Observable<String> { ... }

    /// get userInfo
    static func userInfo(token: String) -> Observable<UserInfo> { ... }
}

Api.token(username: "beeth0ven", password: "987654321")
    .flatMapLatest(Api.userInfo)
    .subscribe(onNext: { userInfo in
        print("获取用户信息成功: \(userInfo)")
    }, onError: { error in
        print("获取用户信息失败: \(error)")
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

[reactivex.io](http://reactivex.io)

https://community.rxswift.org